# What's the behavior of Iterable#all & Why did Kotlin Char::class.java != char.javaClass

Tags: collections, kotlin, typechecking

I'm trying an example in kotlin, like:

```
fun test(){    
    val harfler = listOf("a","b",'c','d')
    println(harfler.all { 
           it.javaClass == String::class.java || it.javaClass == Char::class.java 
    })
}
```

List contains `Char` or `String` but *`all`* function in this expression returns `false`,Why return `false`?

Can anybody explain it?

**Edit**
for @JBNizet
[image]

Comment: If you just added `println(it.javaClass)` inside your closure, you would know.

Comment: `harfler.all { println(it.javaClass) }`required boolean

Comment: Don't **replace** the closure code by that. **add** that line in the closure, right after the opening curly brace.

Comment: i edited questions for that @JBNizet

Comment: But you still haven't read my comment. I never told you to replace the closure code by `it.javaClass`. I told you to **add** the line `println(it.javaClass)` to the closure, right after the opening curly brace.

Comment: i can't **add** line in closure,can you write full code?

Comment: Jeez, this is extremely basic stuff. Adding a line inside a block of code shouldn't be a problem. https://gist.github.com/jnizet/52fca9bf16eae0bef5fd70cc10d035db

Comment: ok but **all** iterator element one by one must be return true in this condition `(it.javaClass == String::class.java || it.javaClass == Char::class.java)`,why return false?

Comment: Have you added the line of code? Have you executed the code with that line added? What does it print? Does it print kotlin.Char.class? Or does it print something else?

Comment: yes i have added, and it prints _class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Character
false_ ,but all function doesnt do compare all items in one condition?

Comment: @JBNizet ok i fixed and understand the problem: https://gist.github.com/natrollus/e5733211143539255a545cdbd29a3708 if you add answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JB Nizet has already told you how to analyze the problem.

According to the [Mapped Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types), The Kotlin `Char` will be mapped to Java Type decide on its declaration.

- when declare as a **non-nullable** type `Char` it is a primitive Java type `char`.
- when declare as a **nullable** type `Char?` it is a Java wrapper type `Character`.
- when declare as a **type argument** `List<Char>` it is a Java wrapper type `Character`.

  ```
  val it = 'a'
  //                v--- it should be `Any`
  val array: Array<Any> = arrayOf('a')

  //          v--- char
  println(it.javaClass)

  //             v--- print [java.lang.Character]  
  println(array.map { it.javaClass })
  ```

---

But I want to say that there is a different between the **usage** and the **declaration**.
For example, the parameter type `it` is a `java.lang.Character`, but its `javaClass` is `char`.

```
fun typeOf(it: Char?) = it?.javaClass

fun test() {
    //                                          v--- java.lang.Character
    println(::typeOf.javaMethod!!.parameterTypes[0])
    //       v--- but it return `char` rather than `java.lang.Character`
    println(typeOf('a'))
}
```

And the example below show the different as further, this is why I declare the array type to `Array<Any>` rather than `Array<Char>` in preceding example:

```
//                v--- uses `java.lang.Character` instead
val array: Array<Char> = arrayOf('a')

//                       v--- java.lang.Character
println(array.javaClass.componentType)
//             v--- [char]
println(array.map { it.javaClass })
```

---

**Why** did the strange behavior occurs in Koltin?

This is because Kotlin `Char` and other wrapper classes represent 2 roles. one is a Java **primitive type** `char`, another is a Java **wrapper** class `java.lang.Character`. However, Kotlin `Char` is **statically** which means you can't change its type in runtime. and a `Char` should be mapped to a `char` by default in Kotlin.

**IF** you want get the wrapper type every time, you should use `KClass.javaObjectType` instead, for example:

```
//                  v--- char 
println(Char::class.java)
//                  v--- java.lang.Character
println(Char::class.javaObjectType)
```

---

The `Iterable#all` operation is a short-circuiting operation, which means if any first element didn't satisfied will return `false` immediately.

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.all(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    //   return `false` immediately the condition didn't satisfied
    //                        v                                            
    for (element in this) if (!predicate(element)) return false
    return true
}
```

---

When checking a Kotlin class like as `Char` and others. you should use the Kotlin [type checking](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#type-checks-and-casts) mechanism rather than traditional comparing approach, it helps you avoid such a confusion. for example:

```
val anything: Array<Any> = arrayOf('a')
val chars: Array<Char> = arrayOf('a')

println(chars.all { it is Char }) // print true
println(anything.all { it is Char }) // print true
```

So your code can replace with [type checking](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#type-checks-and-casts) as below:

```
fun test() {
    val harfler = listOf("a", "b", 'c', 'd')

    //                       v---------------v--- use type checking here 
    println(harfler.all { it is String || it is Char }) // print true
}
```

Comment: @natrollus Not at all. glad it helped you, :)