# Access Integer.class from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a Java method that accepts `Class` parameter. I need to pass `Integer.class` to it, but from Kotlin code. I tried `Int::class.java`, however this does not work, because `int.class` is passed to the function. My question is, how do I access `Integer.class` from Kotlin.

**Java**

```
void foo(Class clazz);
```

**Kotlin**

```
foo(Int::class.java) // does not work, int.class gets passed to foo
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must use the [KClass#javaObjectType](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) to get the wrapper type class in Kotlin:

> Returns a Java `Class` instance corresponding to the given `KClass` instance. In case of **primitive** types it returns corresponding **wrapper** classes.

For example:

```
//                  v--- java.lang.Integer
println(Int::class.javaObjectType)

//                  v--- int
println(Int::class.java)
```

Comment: For the more details you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397859/whats-the-behavior-of-iterableall-why-did-kotlin-charclass-java-char-ja/45400025#45400025).